# How to generate a grid using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, javascript-objects

I need to  to generate a grid (10 rows and 10 cols) using Handlebars. I've created such template:

```
<script id="battlefield-tmpl" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each rows}}
    <div class="battlefield__row">
        {{#each this}}
        <div class="battlefield__cell" data-row="{{this.row}}" data-col="{{this.col}}"></div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Then, here is a script part:

```
const battleFieldTemplate = getTemplate('battlefield-tmpl');

const temp = battleFieldTemplate({
        rows: [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        ]
    }
);
document.querySelector('#battlefield').innerHTML += temp;

function getTemplate(templateId) {
    const templateString = document.getElementById(templateId).innerHTML;
    return Handlebars.compile(templateString);
```

But now I need to create a template, in which every cell will contain row and col index (not the numbers 1,2,3.....10). And it should be generated automatically. I need to receive this:

```
const temp = battleFieldTemplate({
        rows: [
            [{row: 0, col: 0}, {row: 0, col: 1}, {row: 0, col: 2} and so on],
```

but not writing each index manually. 
How to do it?

Comment: Can you not transform your list of objects into a matrix, prior to constructing it the original way? Sometimes it is better to transform your data into a datastructure the program recognizes, prior to creating it.

Comment: Why are all the `col` values the same in your example at the bottom?

Comment: You're right, they should increase.

Comment: OK, it does not look like you need to transform your data structure. After some observation, this is relatively easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

First, render your original data. Make sure your original template works.

```js
const getTemplate = (sel) => Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector(sel).innerHTML);
const battleFieldTemplate = getTemplate('#battlefield-tmpl');

const temp = battleFieldTemplate({
        rows: [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        ]
    }
);

document.querySelector('#battlefield').innerHTML = temp;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.battlefield__row {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.battlefield__cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div id="battlefield"></div>
<script id="battlefield-tmpl" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each rows}}
    <div class="battlefield__row">
        {{#each this}}
        <div class="battlefield__cell">{{.}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Then, you can alter your data structure and change the template slightly... You need to access `{{row}}` without the `this.` portion.

```js
const getTemplate = (sel) => Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector(sel).innerHTML);
const battleFieldTemplate = getTemplate('#battlefield-tmpl');

const temp = battleFieldTemplate({
        rows: [
            [ {row: 0, col: 0}, {row: 0, col: 1}, {row: 0, col: 2} ],
            [ {row: 1, col: 0}, {row: 1, col: 1}, {row: 1, col: 2} ],
            [ {row: 2, col: 0}, {row: 2, col: 1}, {row: 2, col: 2} ]
        ]
    }
);

document.querySelector('#battlefield').innerHTML = temp;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.battlefield__row {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.battlefield__cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div id="battlefield"></div>
<script id="battlefield-tmpl" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each rows}}
    <div class="battlefield__row">
        {{#each this}}
        <div class="battlefield__cell" data-row="{{row}}" data-col="{{col}}">{{row}}×{{col}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'd like not to print indexes in script part. I want them generated automatically. Maybe two-dimensional array is needed to do this...And then they should appear in html grid.

Comment: @Victoria Then post an image or sample HTML of what you DESIRE? I do not know what your result is supposed to be...

Comment: The result should be as you've done: grid with indexes in each col on html page. The main thing is not to print indexes in script file and generate them automatically. Don't want to have this:[ {row: 0, col: 0}, {row: 0, col: 1}, {row: 0, col: 2} {row: 0, col: 3}, {row: 0, col: 4}, {row: 0, col: 5} {row: 0, col: 6}, {row: 0, col: 7}, {row: 0, col: 8} {row: 0, col: 9} ]  for each row in script file.

Comment: @Victoria Can you update the question to include the ACTUAL output you are trying to generate?